# Cursor based pagination using typeorm, typegraphql , postgresql

Tags: pagination, cursor, typeorm, numeric, typegraphql

So i am trying to follow a tutorial but i am getting an error that says

> 'Provided "take" value is not a number. Please provide a numeric value.

So while in the apollo server playground i am getting the results i want, the client side doesnt accept it and it throws the error above, only if i change the

```
.take(realLimitPlusOne);
```

to limit it accepts it but after that it destroys my cursor based pagination logic that i want to follow.

My code is:

In my post.ts file that contains the resolver for Post entity

> 

```js
@Query(() => PaginatedPosts)
  async posts(
    @Arg('limit', () => Int, { nullable: true }) limit: number,
    @Arg('cursor', () => String, { nullable: true }) cursor: string | null
  ): Promise<PaginatedPosts> {
    const realLimit = Math.min(50, limit);
    const realLimitPlusOne = realLimit + 1;

      const qb = AppDataSource.getRepository(Post)
      .createQueryBuilder('p')
      .orderBy('"createdAt"', 'DESC')
      .take(realLimitPlusOne);

    if (cursor) {
      qb.where('"createdAt" < :cursor', {
        cursor: new Date(parseInt(cursor)),
      });
    }

    const posts = await qb.getMany();
    return {
      posts: posts.slice(0, realLimit),
      hasMore: posts.length === realLimitPlusOne,
    };
    
  }
```

In my index.tsx file that represents the client side:

> 

```js
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Flex,
  Heading,
  Link,
  Stack,
  Text,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { PostsDocument, usePostsQuery } from '../generated/graphql';
import { addApolloState, initializeApollo } from '../lib/apolloClient';

// a function that i use in order to do SSR for the query of posts
export const getServerSideProps = async ({
  req,
}: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo({ ctx: { req } });
  await apolloClient.query({ query: PostsDocument });
  return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
    props: {},
  });
};

const Index = () => {
  const { data, loading, fetchMore, variables } = usePostsQuery({
    variables: {
      limit: 10,
      cursor: null,
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });

  if (!loading && !data) {
    return <div>you got query failed for some reason</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Flex>
        <Heading>Lireddit</Heading>
        <Link href="/create-post" ml="auto">
          Create Post
        </Link>
      </Flex>
      <br></br>
      {!data && loading ? (
        <div>loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <Stack spacing={8}>
          {data!.posts.posts.map((p) => (
            <Box p={5} shadow="md" borderWidth="1px" key={p.id}>
              <Heading fontSize="xl">{p.title}</Heading>
              <Text mt={4}>{p.textSnippet}</Text>
            </Box>
          ))}
        </Stack>
      )}
      {data ? (
        <Flex>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              fetchMore({
                variables: {
                  limit: variables?.limit,
                  cursor:
                    data.posts.posts[data.posts.posts.length - 1].createdAt,
                },
              });
            }}
            isLoading={loading}
            m="auto"
            my={8}
          >
            Load more
          </Button>
        </Flex>
      ) : null}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

In my posts.graphql file:

> 

```
query Posts($cursor: String, $limit: Int) {
  posts(cursor: $cursor, limit: $limit) {
    hasMore
    posts {
      id
      title
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      textSnippet
    }
  }
}
```

And finally in my apolloClient.ts file :

> 

```js
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  credentials: 'include',
});

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: from([httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            posts: {
              // Don't cache separate results based on
              // any of this field's arguments.
              keyArgs: false,

              // Concatenate the incoming list items with
              // the existing list items.
              merge(
                existing: PaginatedPosts | undefined,
                incoming: PaginatedPosts
              ): PaginatedPosts {
                return {
                  ...incoming,
                  posts: [...(existing?.posts || []), ...incoming?.posts],
                };
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  });
}
```

My Paginated Posts object:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class PaginatedPosts {
  @Field(() => [Post])
  posts: Post[];
  @Field()
  hasMore: boolean;
}
```

Comment: So i found a solution, i defined the @Arg("limit",{defaultValue: 10})) in order to have a defaultValue that can be accepted cause the error was caused because there wasnt an initial value and it didnt recognize the argument limit as number.

Comment: Have you tried using [`typeorm-pagination`](https://github.com/savannabits/typeorm-pagination)?

Comment: Moreover, it's better if you create a [`PaginationArgs`](https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster/blob/main/server/src/graphql/args/find/many/PaginationArgs.ts#L31) class that contains `skip`, `take` and `cursor` parameters. Then, to add pagination to any `@ArgsType` (e.g. [`FindManyUserArgs`](https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster/blob/main/server/src/graphql/args/find/many/FindManyUserArgs.ts#L32)), simply "extends PaginationArgs." It's much easier and more maintainable.